# How to set iamProfileName in aws.simple.conf

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, cloudera, amazon-iam

Xpost from aws forums.

Hello All,

I am using this guide: https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/cloudera/hadoop/latest/doc/Cloudera_EDH_on_AWS.pdf

I create the cloud and now I have to configure this file: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-quickstart/blob/master/cloudera/media/aws.simple.conf

My question is how do I configure line 151 in aws.simple.conf so all my instances have full access to dynamodb. Can I create a role in my console and somehow link it to that? Or do i have to write some code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any code. You need to create an IAM role before you build the cluster and include it there. Once the cluster comes you, you can modify the permissions on the IAM role associated with the instances, if need be.

Comment: Okay, thanks! i switched tasks a bit, so i'll give this a try sometime soon.